# What is the correct way to perform this sort operation?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Left {get;set}
    public int Right {get;set;}

    public static IEnumerable<Foo> Sorted(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        return foos.OrderBy(x=>x.Left).ThenBy(x=>x.Right);
    }
}
```

Now given a class:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo {get;}

    public IEnumerable<Bar> Sorted(IEnumerable<Bar> bars)
    {
        //Sort the bars by this logic: the order of bars is equivalent to the order of their Foos when sorted by Foo.Sorted().
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to put in my method to perform the correct sort.

Edit: I am also aware that a pure LINQ statement might be had by crafting a `IComparer<T>` class to perform a item-granular comparison, but the given `foos.OrderBy...` LINQ expression is already the intended outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `Sorted` method is unnecessary, but its logic can be used in the `Bars` class.

```
public class Bars
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<Bar> Sorted(IEnumerable<Bar> bars)
    {
        return bars.OrderBy(b => b.Foo?.Left).ThenBy(b => b.Foo?.Right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, technically your answer doesn't use the Foo logic, but it is an entirely separate expression that works.

Comment: As long as your problem is solved, I'm happy. Technicalities notwithstanding.

Comment: is there a way to say "hey foos sort yourself. Now I see you are sorted, we will sort ourselves based on you" so that bar doesnt have to rely on foos properties?

Comment: Possibly, but that would require a much more complicated query, and code spread across two classes, which would be harder to read, debug, and maintain. What would be the advantage of that over the straightforward query above?

Answer (score 0):

You could define an `IComparer<Foo>` and use that:

```
public class FooComparer : IComparer<Foo>
{
    public int Compare(Foo? x, Foo? y)
    {
        if (x.Left == y.Left) x.Right.CompareTo(y.Right);
        return x.Left.CompareTo(y.Left);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Right { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> Sorted(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        return foos.OrderBy(x => x, new FooComparer());
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo {get;}

    public IEnumerable<Bar> Sorted(IEnumerable<Bar> bars)
    {
        return bars.OrderBy(x => x.Foo, new FooComparer());
    }
}
```